# Scheduled Mass Delete of records

Tags: delete, tools, feature-activation

Is there any app, tool or feature that would allow me to schedule Mass Delete of records without using any code. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked in the App Exchange??

Comment: I found this app: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016YuDEAU  however there is no option to schedule the delete task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Dataloader for that, and use the Command Line Interface (CLI). This way, Dataloader can be invoked using the scheduler of your system OS - like Windows Scheduler - to call a batch file that will in turn call the Data Loader.

Through the Dataloader config file, you can automatically login.

To use the Dataloader CLI, you find details here:
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line

Answer (score 2):

Storage Helper mass deletes data from any object in Salesforce and does not require code. You can install free from the AppExchange: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5fvwEAB